# Highstocks individual pane shadow

Tags: highcharts, shadow, panes

Is it possible to have highstocks make each individual pane have its own shadow, rather than the entire plot area? I tried putting the shadow options in the yAxis field but that does not seem to work:

```
            yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: 200,
            lineWidth: 2,
            id: 'OHLC',
            //do it here??
                    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: '#f2f6fb',
        plotShadow: {
            enabled: true,
            width: 6,
            offsetX: 2,
            offsetY: 2
        }
    },
```

aaaand jsfiddler:  http://jsfiddle.net/abbike18/Ww5Tg/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only shadow for full plotting area is supported, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Ww5Tg/8/

You have two options:

- try to use `plotBands` for yAxis, but this may not be sufficient
- use `chart.render.rect()` to add rect where you have pane, with color/options you have to

Comment: Would be nice to see this feature in the future. I will try the 'plotbands' idea and get back

Comment: I agree - create an idea on [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general).

Comment: For future reference, the plotBands workaround does a good job of making each pane stand out, but the shadow would really make each pane "pop"